# datetimepicker jqgrid asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm new in jqGrid and Asp.Net MVC and I have a problem with my datetimepicker!
I downloaded a predefined datetimepicker from this page ( http://xdsoft.net/jquery-plugins/simple-dtpicker/ ) and included it into my Application.
Now my Problem: When I want to add new data to my grid, the datetimepicker doesn't pop-up when I click in the field where I defined it. Maybe someone can help me. Thank you!

Here's my Code:

The line where I call the datetimepicker function is this one:

```
{ key: false, hidden: false, name: 'Beginn', index: 'Beginn', align: 'center', editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {  newformat: 'd-M-Y HH:mm' }, datefmt: 'd-M-Y', timefmt: 'HH:mm', editoptions: {  dataInit: initDate }, width: 50, searchoptions: { clearSearch: false } },


<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/JQGrid/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/JQGrid/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).bind('resize', function () {
        var width1 = $('#jqgrid_container2').width();
        $('#tblJQGridBereitschaft').setGridWidth(width1);
    });


    function Tastensperre(event) {
        var obj = event.srcElement || event.target;
        if (obj.tagName == 'INPUT') return true;
        if (obj.tagName == 'TEXTAREA') return true;
        if (event.keyCode == 18 || event.keyCode == 8) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
          && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('de');

    initDate = function (elem) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(elem).datetimepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm'
            });
        }, 100);
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").jqGrid(
        {
            url: 'Bereitschaft/GetBereitschaft',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['ID','DNR', 'Beginn', 'Ende', 'Feiertag', 'B_ID', 'Bereich', 'Info', 'Phone', 'ST_ID', 'Status'],
            colModel: [
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'ID', index: 'ID', align: 'center', width: 15, searchoptions: { clearSearch: false } },
            { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'DNR', index: 'DNR', align: 'center', editable: true, width: 50, searchoptions: { clearSearch: false } },
            { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'Beginn', index: 'Beginn', align: 'center', editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'd-M-Y HH:mm' }, datefmt: 'd-M-Y', timefmt: 'HH:mm', editoptions: { edithidden: false, dataInit: initDate }, width: 50, searchoptions: { clearSearch: false } },
            { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'Ende', index: 'Ende', align: 'center', editable: true, width: 50, searchoptions: { clearSearch: false } },
            { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'Feiertag', index: 'Feiertag', align: 'center', editable: true, width: 50, searchoptions: { clearSearch: false } },
            { key: false, hidden: true, name: 'B_ID', index: 'B_ID', align: 'center', editable: true, width: 50, searchoptions: { clearSearch: false } },
            { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'Bereich', index: 'Bereich', align: 'center', editable: true, width: 50, searchoptions: { clearSearch: false } },
            { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'Info', index: 'Info', align: 'center', editable: true, width: 50, searchoptions: { clearSearch: false } },
            { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'Phone', index: 'Phone', align: 'center', editable: true, width: 50, searchoptions: { clearSearch: false } },
            { key: false, hidden: true, name: 'ST_ID', index: 'ST_ID', align: 'center', editable: true, width: 50, searchoptions: { clearSearch: false } },
            { key: false, hidden: true, name: 'Status', index: 'Status', align: 'center', editable: true, width: 50, searchoptions: { clearSearch: false } }],
            sortname: 'Beginn',
            viewrecords: false,
            sortorder: "asc",
            scroll: true,
            refresh: true,
            loadonce: true,
            height: 500,
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            rowNum: 20000,
            caption: "",
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                Id: "0"
            },
            gridComplete: function () {
                var myGrid = $("#tblJQGridBereitschaft");
                $("#cb_" + myGrid[0].id).hide();
            },
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                var rid = jQuery('#tblJQGridBereitschaft').jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
                if (rid) {
                    var row = jQuery('#tblJQGridBereitschaft').jqGrid("getRowData", rid);
                }
            },
            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").jqGrid('resetSelection');
                return (true);
            },
            scrollOffset: 0,
            multiselect: true,
            pager: '#JQGridPagerGridBereitschaft',
        });

        /*SEARCH TOOLBAR OF CUSTOMERS FROM SELECTED IMPORT FILE*/
        jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOperators: false });

        $("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").navGrid("#JQGridPagerGridBereitschaft", { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: false },
           {
               /*EDIT*/
               zIndex: 10000,
               rowNum: 1000,
               url: 'Bereitschaft/ModifyBereitschaft',
               closeOnEscape: true,
               closeAfterEdit: true,
               recreateForm: true,
               beforeShowForm: function (form) {
               },
               afterComplete: function (response) {
                   jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").setGridParam({ loadonce: false })
                   jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").setGridParam({ datatype: "json" })
                   jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").setGridParam({ url: '@Url.Action("GetBereitschaft", "Bereitschaft")', page: 1 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                   jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").setGridParam({ loadonce: true })
               }
           },
           {   /*ADD*/
               zIndex: 100000,
               url: "Bereitschaft/CreateBereitschaft",
               closeOnEscape: true,
               closeAfterAdd: true,
               recreateForm: true,
               afterComplete: function (response) {
                   jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").setGridParam({ loadonce: false })
                   jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").setGridParam({ datatype: "json" })
                   jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").setGridParam({ url: '@Url.Action("GetBereitschaft", "Bereitschaft")', page: 1 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                   jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").setGridParam({ loadonce: true })
               }
           },
           {    /*DELETE*/
                zIndex: 10000,
                url: "Bereitschaft/DeleteBereitschaft",
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterDelete: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                afterComplete: function (response) {
                    jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").setGridParam({ loadonce: false })
                    jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").setGridParam({ datatype: "json" })
                    jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").setGridParam({ url: '@Url.Action("GetBereitschaft", "Bereitschaft")', page: 1 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                    jQuery("#tblJQGridBereitschaft").setGridParam({ loadonce: true })
                 }
           }
           );
    });

</script>
```

Hope you could help me. Would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have embed all reference link in hierarchical 
1) First load all css file ..
2) Load jquery  , jqgrid , date picker

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="jquery.simple-dtpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/JQGrid/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- link here jqgrid jqGrid.min.js -->
<!-- link here jqgrid grid.locale-en.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.simple-dtpicker.js"></script>
```

Simple bootstrap date picker example with jqgrid

refference :

```
<link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_5.2.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_5.2.0/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_5.2.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_5.2.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```

colModel as below :

```
 { name: 'Date', index: 'Date', editable: true, edittype: 'text',
                    editable: true,
                    editrules:
                        {  required: true, },     
                editoptions: {
                    size: 10, maxlengh: 10,
                    dataInit: function(element) {
                        $(element).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy.mm.dd'})
                    }

                }},
```

i hope this work fine ...

Comment: first i suggest you use simple bootstrap date picker , then go for this